# Node File System unstable

Tags: node.js, fs

In Node.js, I noticed that file operations were not always stable. I have the impression that `fs` gives up when the operations are not completely finished. Here is an example to illustrate:

```
"use strict";

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

const fs = require("fs");
const filename = "foo.txt";

for (let i = 0; ; i++) {
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(filename, "bar");
        fs.unlinkSync(filename);
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw Object.assign(new Error(`Error at iteration ${i}!`), { cause: e });
    }
}
```

After a certain number of iterations, I get an error :

```
Error: Error at iteration 12980!
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\test.js:15:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  cause: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'foo.txt'
      at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
      at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1384:35)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\test.js:10:6)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    errno: -4048,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'EPERM',
    path: 'foo.txt'
  }
}
```

- Do you have the same observation?
- How can we ensure that these operations are stable?

Comment: Despite the error you got I strongly recommend to use `writeFile` from `fs/promises`

Comment: This is likely specific to an OS or filesystem (looks like you're using Windows?), and it may be beyond Node.js's control. I can't reproduce it on macOS (I stopped the program after 200.000 iterations), but UNIX filesystems typically don't care about files already being opened.

Comment: Yes I am on Windows 7 ^^'

Comment: Try providing path more carefully: `require("path").resolve(__dirname, "foo.txt")`